# How to Tree shake @carbon/charts-react?

Tags: rollup, tree-shaking

I am building a react component lib, this lib has `@carbon/charts-react` as dependency.

in one of the component I am importing `RadarChart` from `@carbon/chars-react`
and this the only component from `@carbon/charts-react` that I am using in lib.

```
import { RadarChart as RadarChartCarbon } from '@carbon/charts-react';
```

the problem:

when I run rollup to build the lib I noticed the whole `@carbon/charts-react` is included in the build.

Ho to include only the `RadarChart` component in build? Thanks in advance.

here is rollup config:

```
export default {
  input: 'src/index.js',
  output: [
    {
      format: 'es',
      dir: 'build',
      // preserveModules: true,
      // preserveModulesRoot: 'src',
      // sourcemap: false,
    },
  ],

  plugins: [
    peerDepsExternal(),
    typescript({
      module: 'ESNext',
      declarationDir: './build',
    }),
    commonjs({
      include: 'node_modules/**',
      namedExports: {
        'react-is': ['isForwardRef', 'isValidElementType'],
      },
    }),
    resolve({
      preferBuiltins: true,
    }),
    babel({
      babelHelpers: 'runtime',
      exclude: 'node_modules/**',
      presets: ['@babel/preset-react'],
      plugins: [['@babel/plugin-transform-runtime', { useESModules: true }]],
    }),
    postcss({
      to: './build/base.css',
      preprocessor: (content, id) =>
        new Promise(res => {
          const result = sass.renderSync({ file: id });

          res({ code: result.css.toString() });
        }),
      plugins: [url(options), autoprefixer],
      modules: {
        scopeBehaviour: 'global',
      },
      extract: 'base.css',
      use: [
        [
          'sass',
          {
            includePaths: ['./node_modules'],
          },
        ],
      ],
    }),
    json(),
    terser(),
    del({ targets: 'build/*' }),
    visualizer({
      open: true,
    }),
  ],
};
```

[RadarChart](https://github.com/carbon-design-system/carbon-charts/blob/master/packages/react/src/charts/RadarChart.tsx)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly the library `@carbon/charts-react` isn't tree-shakable.

[image: screen]

(tested with [agadoo](https://www.npmjs.com/package/agadoo))

So however you import as long as it is from `index.js` it will take everything in the final bundle.

What you can do is import like that:

```
  import RadarChartCarbon from 'Relative/path/to/node_modules/@carbon/charts-react/dist/charts/RadarChart';
```

This way, you will only take the chart you want in your final bundle.

Hope it helps you ! :)